# UIControl not responding properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've created a custom `UIControl` with an image and a title vertical and horizontal aligned, one on the top of the other that should act as a `UIButton`.

The problem is that when I call out the `addTarget()` to add an action when the element is touch inside, the action doesnt perform well, only after a cuple of taps does the job.

What can cause this issue?

Thank you.

Here is the class for this UIControl element.

```
class CustomImageTitleButton: UIControl {

    private var image : UIImageView = UIImageView()

    private var title : UILabel = UILabel()

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.backgroundColor = PrimaryLightColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 20

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(image)
        self.addSubview(title)

        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        title.textAlignment = .center
        title.font = title.font.withSize(24)

        setupConstraints()
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0),
            image.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 8),

            title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 4),
            title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
            title.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setImage(image : UIImage?) {
        self.image.image = image
    }

    func setTitle(title : String?) {
        self.title.text = title
    }
}
```

And here is the implementation of the action:

```
singlePlayerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(initSinglePlayerGame), for: .touchUpInside) // singlePlayerButton is the custom UIControl

@objc func initSinglePlayerGame() {
        print("single player tapped")
        let gameRoom : GameViewController =  GameViewController()
        gameRoom.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(gameRoom, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

EDIT:

It looks like the UIControl manages the user interaction but isn't a simple tap, it's more like a "tap, drag and release" action.

Comment: its working quite well at my end ... control is good enough ... there can be something else sir

Comment: please share the code where you add this control

Answer (score 0):

you can use [HitTest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest) to determine UI Control's event handling.

Also, you can check the UI view hierarchy if the UIControl is to the top of the view hierarchy.

Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy